# TypeScript: How to constrain a generic method's return type to depend on argument type?

Tags: typescript

**How should the return type of `getStreamFor$(item: Item)` be constrained to depend on method parameter type `Item`?**

*What I need is:*

- when I call `getStream$(Item.Car)` to have the type of `stream$` as `Observable<CarModel>`
- when I call `getStream$(Item.Animal)`, to have the type of `stream$` as `Observable<AnimalModel>`

Now the type of `stream$` is `Observable<CarModel | AnimalModel | TemperatureModel>`.

(see the place commented 'HERE', [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xxob5j?file=style.css))

```
enum Item {
  CAR = 'car',
  ANIMAL = 'animal',
  TEMPERATURE = 'temperature'
}

interface CarModel {
  make: string;
}

interface AnimalModel {
  breed: string;
}

interface TemperatureModel {
  tmp: number;
  scale: string;
}

class Channel {
  stream: {
    [prop in Item]: Observable<CarModel | AnimalModel | TemperatureModel>
  };

  constructor() {
    this.stream = {
      [Item.CAR]: of({ make: 'Ford' }) as Observable<CarModel>,
      [Item.ANIMAL]: of({ breed: 'Cat' }) as Observable<AnimalModel>,
      [Item.TEMPERATURE]: of({ tmp: 35, scale: 'Celsius' }) as Observable<TemperatureModel>
    };
  }

  getStreamFor$(item: Item): Observable<CarModel | AnimalModel | TemperatureModel> {
    return this.stream[item];
  }
}

const c = new Channel();
const stream$ = c.getStreamFor$(Item.CAR) // <--- HERE
  .pipe(
    map((value) => {
      value.make // <--- '.make' is marked as error by IDE
    }),
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

By [annotating](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `stream` as `{ [K in Item]: Observable<CarModel | AnimalModel | TemperatureModel> }`, you've made the compiler forget about the particular mapping between each key from `Item` and each model.  Similarly, by annotating the return type of `getStreamFor$()` as `Observable<CarModel | AnimalModel | TemperatureModel>`, that function can do nothing but return the wide union type that you're having problems with. If you want the return type of `getStreamFor$(item)` to depend on the the type of `item`, then you need to make it a [generic method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) (or else make it an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), but I wouldn't recommend that).

---

The easiest way to proceed here to get the typing you'd like is to remove these annotations and let the compiler *infer* the types.  For `stream` that means you need to use a class field initializer instead of a declaration:

```
class Channel {
  stream = {
    [Item.CAR]: of({ make: 'Ford' }) as Observable<CarModel>,
    [Item.ANIMAL]: of({ breed: 'Cat' }) as Observable<AnimalModel>,
    [Item.TEMPERATURE]: of({ tmp: 35, scale: 'Celsius' }) as Observable<
      TemperatureModel
    >
  };

  constructor() {}
```

And then just make `getStreamFor$()` generic in type parameter `I` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Item`, where `I` is the type of the passed-in `item` parameter:

```
  getStreamFor$<I extends Item>(item: I) {
    return this.stream[item];
  }
}
```

Now everything will just work:

```
const c = new Channel();
const stream$ = c.getStreamFor$(Item.CAR).pipe(
  map(value => {
    value.make; // okay now
  })
);
```

You can stop there if you want.

---

Now, if you use IntelliSense you can see the inferred types of `stream` and `getStreamFor$`:

```
/* (property) Channel.stream: {
    car: Observable<CarModel>;
    animal: Observable<AnimalModel>;
    temperature: Observable<TemperatureModel>;
}

(method) Channel.getStreamFor$<I extends Item>(item: I): {
    car: Observable<CarModel>;
    animal: Observable<AnimalModel>;
    temperature: Observable<TemperatureModel>;
}[I] */
```

Note how the that return type is expressed in terms of `stream`'s type.  So if you want to annotate things, you should probably give names to `stream`'s type and use it to annotate:

```
interface ItemModelMap {
  [Item.CAR]: Observable<CarModel>;
  [Item.ANIMAL]: Observable<AnimalModel>;
  [Item.TEMPERATURE]: Observable<TemperatureModel>;
}

class Channel {
  stream: ItemModelMap;
  constructor() {
    this.stream = {
      [Item.CAR]: of({ make: 'Ford' }),
      [Item.ANIMAL]: of({ breed: 'Cat' }),
      [Item.TEMPERATURE]: of({ tmp: 35, scale: 'Celsius' })
    };
  }

  getStreamFor$<I extends Item>(item: I): ItemModelMap[I] {
    return this.stream[item];
  }
}
```

Since `stream` is annotated as `ItemModelMap`, you don't need to use `as Observable<CarModel>` etc. in its initializer.  And you can move the initialization back inside the `constructor()` method if you want.  And finally the return type of `getStreamFor$()` can be expressed fairly simply as `ItemModelMap[I]`.

Everything still works how you want, and now you have strong type annotations.

[Stackblitz link to code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-sysbo6?file=style.css)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, exactly an approach like `ItemModelMap` is what I've been looking as in my example I've purposefully done the declaration in one line as in the real world case it's assigned dynamically and what I was looking for is the proper formulation of `type constraint`, so that if you ask for `Item.CAR` IDE locks your stream to `CarModel`